# Convergence of off-shell loop integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, integration, regularization

Given the following theory

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\dot\varphi^2-\frac{1}{2M^2}(\Delta\varphi)^2-\frac{m^2}{2}\varphi^2-\frac{g}{4!}\varphi^4$$

it's easy to show that the free propagator ($g=0$) in Fourier space is given by

$$G(p^0,p) = \frac{i}{(p^0)^2-\dfrac{|p|^2}{M^2}-m^2+i\epsilon}.$$

I want to compute the one-loop corrections to the coupling constant $g$ in the off-shell configuration, so setting all external momenta to zero. Being this a sort of $g \varphi^4$ theory (which i imagine being regularized by the presence of the $M$ term). We know that there are three one loop corrections that are related all to the same loop integral. In the off-shell configuration this integral is of the form

$$\int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{\left((k^0)^2-\dfrac{|k|^2}{M^2}-m^2+i\epsilon\right)^2} \tag{1}$$

In my mind this integral should converge to something along the lines of $m^2/M^2$ or $m^2/M^2$, but it's just a gut feeling. By computing it with the help of wolframalpha I find this feeling to be correct. Then I try to solve it in the following way

$$\int dk^0d^3k\frac{1}{\left((k^0)^2-\dfrac{|k|^2}{M^2}-m^2+i\epsilon\right)^2} = M^3\int dk^0d^3k \frac{1}{\left((k^0)^2-|k^2|-m^2+i\epsilon\right)^2}\\ = \int d^4k \frac{1}{\left(k^2-m^2+i\epsilon\right)^2}$$

where in the second to last step I used the change of variable $k\to k/M$. But I know that this integral does not converge since, if we regularize it, we get someghing along the lines of

$$\int^\Lambda d^4k \frac{1}{\left(k^2-m^2+i\epsilon\right)^2} \propto \log\frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}$$

> What's wrong in my evaluation? How should the integral $(1)$ be computed?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your evaluation. This is standard $\phi^4$ theory ($M$ is a parameter like $c$ that we can get rid of by redefining our length scales) and the integral is indeed logarithmically divergent.

Comment: @octonion But the problem this is coming from says that the off-shell one loop corrections to $g$ should be finite.

Comment: It occurred to me $\Delta$ is probably actually the Laplacian not $\nabla$. So this really isn't the $\phi^4$ theory but you should have a $p^4$ in your propagator that should end up regularizing the integrals.

Comment: @octonion You're totally right! Thank you very much. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @octonion This even solves the dimensional problem I was having.